# Cannot login into amazon.com

Tags: authentication, amazon

I have bought a laptop on Amazon a couple days ago. I would like to login to check my order, but I cannot login into amazon.com or amazon.fr.

What I have tried:

- Tried to change password (click forgot password, go to email, go to reset page, and enter new password). Then the new password does't work.
- Tried to save new password into clipboard to make sure the new one is the one I type
- Tried to wait a few minutes after password reset
- Tried to reset in a Chrome new private window (no cookies)
- Tried to reset in IE
- Tried to reset via amazon.com, amazon.fr, amazon.co.uk
- I have noticed that even if I am not logged in, Amazon recognizes me (probably with cookies)
- Ran a Microsoft Security Essentials scan

[image]

So I have tried to click sign out before signin in. (Note that in this situation, if I click "my orders" I have to sign in. So in this state, recognized but not signed in.)

I am running out of ideas. What do you suggest?

Comment: Cleared cookies too?

Comment: Just tried, yes

Comment: I would assume you don't have cookies enabled or similar - when you're saving your password, it's not storing any data on your machine and so can't authenticate you.

Comment: @DaveRook I do have cookies enabled

Comment: Please type this into the search bar or run bar (assuming Windows) iexplore -extoff  This will load IE with no plug ins. Try amazon now and we'll see if this does it.

Comment: @DaveRook I've tried the whole process of re-initializing the password on IE with no addons, same problem. The problem might actually be on the amazon servers... (which I find hard to believe)

Comment: And at the risk of saying something stupid, but how long are you trying between attempts - Amazon won't allow you on within 15 minutes of last login and I'm not sure if this time is reset upon each attempt.

Comment: I suggest you call customer service:
Amazon customer service in the US and Canada: (800) 201-7575
Amazon customer service outside the US and Canada: (206) 346-2992 or (206)-266-2992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that my account has been frozen (even tough on login, the message is "incorrect email or password"). Amazon wanted me to send them a document by fax to prove my identity.

I have no fax. I ended up creating another account.

Comment: I have the same problem, I cant login , I change password, it shows success message, but it is till cannot login,.........Ghu ghu ghu